# Visual Studio Coded UI: recording AND adding assertions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, browser, user-interface

I'm very, very new to this tool and I'm just starting to experiment with it.

I want to test a simple web page. When I create a new Test, I'm asked to record it. I fire up IE, click the record button on the popup and type in an address (eg google.com). The problem is that the "Add Assertion" button is grayed out as soon as i press record.

So how can I record the act of browsing to www.google.com **and** asserting that, for example, there is a button with the label "Search"? Seems like I can either record **or** make assertions and this doesn't make sense to me, as I want to automate performing various actions *and* checking for specific results.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to record and do an assertion at the same time. With coded UI tests I have found it is best to keep my recorded actions relatively short and specific. Fill out a form and click to next page make assertions about the next page, record a new action for that page. Longer action recordings seem to break more often and are harder to update.